# tcsh: how to enter a subdirectory that's most recently modified?

Tags: command-line, shell, tcsh

I found it for bash, but how would I do it for tcsh? I want to chain it with a cd command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`ls -dt */ | head -1`
```

works for me. I can use it with `cd` or set it to an environment variable.